# Change the Theme into UI Darkness

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Goal:
Change the theme into 'UI darkness'

Problem:
I don't know how to do it based on the code below.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#from").datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,      
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


  
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the CSS file's CDN link to the theme you want:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#from").datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    

    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      showWeek: true,
      firstDay: 1,      
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",      
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


  
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```